# How to use a texture in the size of the original image in threejs / react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a difficulty in a project, I need to create a box to optimize processing, I would like the texture to be 16 px by 16 px. When I apply it to the box, regardless of the size of the box, it gets blur like the image below. Is there a possibility to set the pixels of the texture to look exactly like the image? Without using a large image?

Resulting using a 16 x 16 pixel image.
[image]

Resulting using a 500 x 16 pixel image.
[image]

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780592/how-to-render-pixelated-textures-with-three-js/15780593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by adding a filter on the texture:
Example:

```js
import dirtImg from './images/dirt.jpg';
export const dirt = new TextureLoader().load(dirtImg);
dirt.magFilter = NearestFilter;
dirt.minFilter = LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not as lucky... the image (512x512) I applied to Texture will be shrinked so much that it is useless. There are something like 12x12 images repeated across the UV plane.

I'm using texture.repeat.set(1,1).

[image]

Using a much larger image will give the same total number of images in the grid, with the image more pixelated.

[image]

I don't know how to adjust the image so that exactly 1 image will fit into the geometry.

It seems counter-intuitive, but I can use:

> texture.repeat.set(0.1,0.1)

to enlarge the image.

[image]

but this is not suitable as the image will be applied dynamically.

This has been dragging on for 2 months now, and I still can't figure out a solution.

Do you have any idea about which threejs parameter to set? Below is my existing code:

> ```
> let dirtImg = "/logo192.png";
> const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(dirtImg);
> texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;     // no effect
> texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;    // no effect
> texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;  // has effect
> texture.flipY  = false;          // has effect
> texture.repeat.set(1,1);         // has effect
> const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {map: texture} );
> ```